# Vite rollupOptions and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite, rollupjs

I have a typescript file in which I define and export a js class like so :

```js
export class Hello {
    constructor() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
```

I import this class in a `<script type="module">` :

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="module">
import {Hello} from './Hello.ts';

new Hello();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I build with Vite, here are my config files :

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  }
}
```

I have a custom vite.config.js because I need the output file to be in a custom directory (not in the default dist) and without hashing:

```js
import {defineConfig} from "vite";
import {resolve} from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        sourcemap: true,
        outDir: '',
        assetsDir: '',
        rollupOptions: {
            input: resolve(__dirname, 'Hello.ts'),
            output: {
                entryFileNames: "[name].js"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Running `npm run dev` works.

But when I run the `npm run build` script, the generated Hello.js is empty.

I guess the issue come from the rollupOptions because if I disable those, it works, but as I said, I need to customize the outputDir and output file name.

Thank you.